# Connect LoopBack4 to REST API and Swagger

Tags: node.js, rest, swagger, loopback4

I'm a lb3 user and trying to migrate lb3 projects to lb4. But I got some troubles in doing this: 
How can I invoke another micro service via swagger/rest connector?
I looked into the officeal document and get some links:

1. [swagger connector](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-openapi)
2. [rest connector](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-rest).

But they are both lb3 based code. Are ther any examples for lb4?

Comment: There is an official guide: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Calling-other-APIs-and-web-services.html